# PostgreSQL Проверка на уникальность с условием

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица с уникальным полем - name, также есть поле is_deleted, как сделать чтобы PostgreSQL добавлял запись не учитывая при проверке на уникальность те записи где is_deleted - true?

Comment: в теории на столбец namу прикрутить проверку `check` (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/ddl-constraints)

Comment: удалять не надо, нужно передать информацию потом о тех которые удалили (т.е обновили в моем случае)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то [так](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/311586/) думаю.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_unique_idx ON users(name) WHERE is_deleted = false;
```